# AJAX call goes to file location instead of actual URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created a html JS project.
I am calling AJAX function with URL but in the browser console, I see URL as `Request URL: file:///C:/localhost:8080/allProducts`

I want to call `localhost:8080/allProducts`

Code snippet:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/localhost:8080/allProducts',
  ....
  ..
```

Comment: Typo. You forgot the `http:/` part of the URL.

Comment: So your browser is loading the file off the file system and not a server so it will use the file system. Also url should be `//localhost....` So how you are running your application is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `localhost:8080` portion of the URL. Assuming `allProducts` is some sort of file in the root directory, I would put `url: /allProducts`.

Then, if you end up pushing this into a production server it will look for `allProducts` at the root directory level, no matter the hostname.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the protocol as in the following example:

`http:///localhost:8080/allProducts`